# reading a long long type _RecordsetPtr C++

Tags: c++, database, oracle, ado

I am getting a long long type returned from my oracle function and I am trying to parse it using the below code

```
// pVal holds the output of function
pTempRS = (_RecordsetPtr) pVal;
pTempRS->Fields->GetItem((long)0)->Value.lVal;
```

The problem is it is overflowing therefore it works fine when the result returned is in INT_MAX range(~10**9) but negative value is show in case of value returned from function is greater than INT MAX range.
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you would have to provide more code and./or types that you are using, these two lines are not enough at all

Comment: @OlegBogdanov my oracle function returns numeric type. I wanted to know is it possible to parse long long type returned from oracle.

Comment: I think I need to use _variant_t but don't know how

Comment: absolutely, but its not clear what is the function you are mentioning, is it `GetItem`? if so its not clear how do yiu parse, you need to include minimal code